# How to setup a simple reverse proxy in docker?

Tags: nginx, docker, containers

I am new in docker. I have of applications running on multiple container. Now, I would like to publish all my apps. What I am planning to do is do make a cluster containning all my application. I want at least 4 containers.

1. Nginx container that is facing internet like a reverse proxy. He is responsible to redirect traffic to other containers, since there are not directly accessible through internet.
2. Node_js container that publishes a web in nodejs (http://www.node-app.me).
3. java_EE container that publishes Java EE application (http://www.java_ee-app.me).
4. Django container that publishes a Django application(http://www.django-app.me).

This is the idear I have, but I don't no how to set nginx container to play the proxy role and make the request to the correct container so that if user send a request like http://www.node-app.me, the container nginx will return result from Node_js, and so on. Can you please give idear on where to start ?

The setup could look like this (sorry I am not very good at drawing) : [image]

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a specific need for nginx, I suggest you use [Træfik](https://traefik.io) to do the reverse proxy. It can be configured to dynamically pick up reverse proxy rules via labels on your containers. Here's a basic example.

First, create a common network for Træfik and your three containers.

```
docker network create traefik
```

Run Træfik with port 80 exposed and the docker backend enabled.

```
docker run --name traefik \
-p 80:80 \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
--network traefik \
traefik:1.2.3-alpine \
--entryPoints='Name:http Address::80' \
--docker \
--docker.watch
```

Run your three services with the appropriate labels. Make sure they share a common network with Træfik so that Træfik can reach it. The `node_js` one might look something like this.

```
docker run --name node_js \
--network traefik \
--label 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.node-app.me' \
--label 'traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http' \
--label 'traefik.port=80' \
--label 'traefik.protocol=http' \
your_node_js_image
```

Træfik will dynamically create a frontend rule that matches on the `Host` header for `www.node-app.me` when it sees this container running. The `traefik.port` and `traefik.protocol` labels let Træfik know how to communicate with your container.

See the documentation for [Træfik's Docker backend](https://docs.traefik.io/toml/#docker-backend) for more options and details.