# My reverse proxy setup with traefik and docker is not resolving web server address

Tags: docker, traefik

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy using docker [traefik](https://traefik.io/). Here is my setup (I am trying to user [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43702895/4796042) ):

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
cool-app            latest              3000cae089df        4 hours ago         927.2 MB
traefik             1.2.3-alpine        ea941f2b2800        3 weeks ago         46.91 MB
node                6.9                 cde8ba396275        3 months ago        658.6 MB
```

I used this to start trafik :

```
docker run --name traefik \
-p 80:80 \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
--network traefik \
traefik:1.2.3-alpine \
--entryPoints='Name:http Address::80' \
--docker \
--docker.watch
```

and this to start my web:

```
docker run --name node_js \
--network traefik \
--label 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.node-app.me' \
--label 'traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http' \
--label 'traefik.port=80' \
--label 'traefik.protocol=http' cool-app
```

after I started both, my docker ps is

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
d00e0cf117fa        cool-app               "/bin/sh -c 'ng serve"   33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       80/tcp               node_js
5a6bd0b1c3c7        traefik:1.2.3-alpine   "/entrypoint.sh '--en"   35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   traefik
```

docker inspect network part is `cool-app` :

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "7a549fc826b2c1d8d25917a374e519c90a93a91e863ffe825a69e41b36347875",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "80/tcp": null
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7a549fc826b2",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
        "traefik": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": [
                "d00e0cf117fa"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "f8894d7c7cfdda1f3c4de805e0a6407aa0a3a5560e6c8c1c9505c12445027241",
            "EndpointID": "25b27deb775e16f26807845dead64a31e5d120ad9162523943d9ac8625283f6b",
            "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03"
        }
    }
}
```

}

docker inspect network part is `traefik` :

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "9b20b8465eb4cf3cbb85b082220ae90f76e8f6ba220d4c3b5f2b06c7149760c4",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "80/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "80"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/9b20b8465eb4",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
        "traefik": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": [
                "5a6bd0b1c3c7"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "f8894d7c7cfdda1f3c4de805e0a6407aa0a3a5560e6c8c1c9505c12445027241",
            "EndpointID": "4a39ccb693e1fdcdbf99937469029768f0542c1df71059f43bbf500c1ebc5b1d",
            "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02"
        }
    }
}
```

}

It seem like web app started correctly, but when I try to access I got :

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.node-app.me
```

Can you please help to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because that domain doesn't exist and you're not providing any local resolution for curl to know where to go.

To get it working quickly, you could modify your hosts file (/etc/hosts):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost www.node-app.me
```

Another common way of doing this, without modifying your hosts file is to utilise http://xip.io/

Comment: But the weird thing is that when I try to open the same URL, **without** adding any changes to the `hosts` file, in the browser or Postman, everything works just fine. At the same time trying to `curl` it fails with `Could not resolve host` error.

Comment: @dodbrian In my case on MacOS, this is because Chrome automatically resolves any `*.localhost` domain to `127.0.0.1`, however neither curl nor Safari do this. So as far as I know you'll have to touch `/etc/hosts`, send requests to localhost with the correct host header (e.g. `curl -H "host: example.localhost" localhost` should work) or use something like `http://localhost/example` and configure the correct service in traefik.